# How to check gaps in a String sequence derived from file names

Tags: scala

I have extract file name into list as follow using Scala. The list contain files name inside given directory.

```
List(MSC050120170625003233176482GCDR.dat.00.IUC, MSC050120170625002444176481GCDR.dat.00.IUC,MSC050120170625010103176485GCDR.dat.00.IUC, MSC050120170625001111176479GCDR.dat.00.IUC, MSC050120170625000513176478GCDR.dat.00.IUC, MSC050120170625000000176477GCDR.dat.00.IUC,...etc)
```

In this list, the name of file will consist in some format as follow.

- MSC050 is gateway
- 20170625003233 is date and time
- 176482 is id(It will increment in sequence).

What i want to check whether id is in sequence order (increment order) by checking filename inside directory using Scala. Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? And what do you mean "check whether ... in order"? Files in a directory have no intrinsic order. File names in a `List` can be rearranged to any desired order. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If there is any issue there can be missing files inside directory where files are included. Then, I want to validate that kind of incident by extracting filename inside of directory using Scala.

Comment: As a example, If missing file consist of id=176483 then I want to notify that situation by validating filenames inside given directory to future purposes. That why I called it as checking whether the file sequence in an order or not.

Comment: Ah, so your _real_ question is: find if there are gaps in a `String` sequence derived from file names.

Comment: I am tired to getting id into list by referring filename inside given directory using Scala

Comment: Yes, I want to check there is gaps in a String sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a very simple test for the condition in question.

```
def isContiguous(filenames: List[String]): Boolean =
  if (filenames.length < 2) true
  else
   filenames.map(_.substring(21,27).toInt)
            .sorted
            .sliding(2)
            .forall(x=>x(1)-x(0) == 1)
```

This isn't completely safe because it will throw an exception if the filename isn't long enough or if the `substring()` from the filename can't be converted to an `Int`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank for solving my problem

Comment: I have some question on this Scala code. What is purpose of using .sliding(2) operation there?

Comment: Try this in the REPL: `"somestring".sliding(2).toList` You can read about it [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sliding(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]).

Comment: Ok thank for contribute my question given me your valuable time to solve this problem.